# "It is not possible to profile 32-bit and 64-bit applications at the same time" error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, profiling

I'm launching a performance profiler for an ASP.NET MVC 3 project in Visual Studio 2012 using "Analyse" -> "Launch performance wizard..." and there choosing "Instrumentation" and selecting my project (because I need to measure the timing and determine the longest function call).

But this gives an error message

`It is not possible to profile 32-bit and 64-bit applications at the same time`

and the profiling process is terminated. I've tried to change platform target to x86, x64, Any CPU but this does not help. What can cause such an error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It appeared that I had multiple projects included, not the only one I've tried to profile (so it is possible that one of that projects was compiled to different architecture). After choosing only my single project profiling worked correctly.